# jQuery Autocomplete: [Object object] showing instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete to select a value from a database. Everything about this is working just fine, with one exception. For the life of me, I cannot get the textbox I am writing the search value in to display the actual value after I have selected it.

I have read people having this problem many times, however the solutions they are presented are not working for me.

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/p8y7111p/

The autocomplete code is:

```
$("#student_search").autocomplete({
  source: "functions/find_student.php",
  delay: 50,
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var name_person = ui.item.label; // this works to give me the name of the person
    var house = ui.item.value.house;
    var id = ui.item.value.id;
    highlightStudent(name_person, id, house);
    $('#student_search').val(name);
  }
});
```

Note that I have tried:

- replacing `name` with `ui.label.value`
- trying adding a close or change property to autocomplete, with `$('#student_search').val(name)` as its value
- placing the `$('#student_search').val(name)` outside of the autocomplete

I literally cannot think of anywhere else to put stuff, and so I turn to you all.

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work - could you recreate a workable version that produces your error?

Comment: Where does `name` come from? Did you mean `name_person`?

Comment: You've not defined anything for the `close` attribute in the fiddle, which is why there's an error. Either remove the attribute or define a function.

Comment: Can you add a sample AJAX response?

Comment: This is the kind of response I am getting:

    {"item":{"label":"Alexander Bunting","value":{"id":6,"house":"s"}}}

Everything that collects values from the response is working, it is literally only that one box that is not using the value correctly. ui.item.label is absolutele returning "Alexander Bunting".

name is name_person, they are the same value - my code snipped above does not show this but they have the same value and type.

The close attribute is still there by accident, from when I was trying anything to get it to work. It still returns object object without it.

Comment: @AlexanderBunting You should really fix the syntax errors by yourself and share a working fiddle demonstrating the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried  `event.preventDefault();`?

The default behavior of the select event is to update the input with ui.item.value. This code runs after your event handler.

Simply prevent the default action on select and focus(not done here) using `event.preventDefault()` or by `return false` and it will work fine.

```
$("#student_search").autocomplete({
  source: "functions/find_student.php",
  delay: 50,
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name_person = ui.item.label; 
    var house = ui.item.value.house;
    var id = ui.item.value.id;
    highlightStudent(name_person, id, house);
    $('#student_search').val(name_person);
  }
});
```

Here is a working solution : [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/p8y7111p/2/)

Comment: I'm still getting the [object object] when doing a keydown on the items in the dropdown. Any idea?